# Structures and linked lists (C)

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list to hold history information.

The definition for my node structure is as follows:

```
struct HistoryNode {
    int Value;
    struct HistoryNode *Last, *Next;
};
```

I've also created another structure to contain pointers to the head/tail/current nodes in the list:

```
struct _History {
    struct HistoryNode *Head, *Tail, *Current;
} History = {
    NULL, NULL, NULL,
};
```

Finally I've created a function to add a node to the list:

```
void AddHistory(void) {
    struct HistoryNode *NewNode;

    //Allocate new node memory
    NewNode = malloc(sizeof(NewNode));
    if(NewNode == NULL) {
        Die("malloc(%d) failed", sizeof(NewNode));
    }

    //Re-arrange pointers in new node and head/tail/current
    if(History.Current == NULL) {
        NewNode->Next = NULL;
        NewNode->Last = NULL;

        History.Current = NewNode;
        History.Head = NewNode;
        History.Tail = NewNode;
    } else {
        NewNode->Next = NULL;
        NewNode->Last = History.Current;

        History.Current = NewNode;
        History.Tail = NewNode;
    }
}
```

GCC spits this back out along with several errors:

```
Scribe.c: In function 'AddHistory':
Scribe.c:509:15: error: request for member 'Current' in something not a structure or union
Scribe.c:513:16: error: request for member 'Current' in something not a structure or union
Scribe.c:514:16: error: request for member 'Head' in something not a structure or union
Scribe.c:515:16: error: request for member 'Tail' in something not a structure or union
Scribe.c:518:32: error: request for member 'Current' in something not a structure or union
Scribe.c:520:16: error: request for member 'Current' in something not a structure or union
Scribe.c:521:16: error: request for member 'Tail' in something not a structure or union
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, any help?

Thanks,
- Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `History` is declared as a global variable, the compilation is successful as seen in http://cfiddle.net/LwucyB . One additional note on the question is related to the allocation of `NewNode` which should be as below

```
NewNode = malloc(sizeof(struct HistoryNode));
```

You need to allocate space for the structure and not just the pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct... "History" is defined as an object of type _History globally. If I make the changes you suggest I get this from GCC:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5341710

Comment: @user1509246.. Can you please share the complete file. If `History` is a global variable, then I could build it locally. Please check this link: http://cfiddle.net/LwucyB

Comment: Posting the complete source file probably wouldn't help much as it's MASSIVE and you'd probably get lost within the bowels of it. However the link you posted is identical to what is in the source file.

Could it be that my compiler doesn't support it? I'm using:

gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: @user1509246.. I doubt if the compiler is issue here. My local compiler is `gcc (GCC) 4.6.2` which seems to be a closer version of your compiler and it is working fine. I have recreated your error here: http://cfiddle.net/ffjaqs which is the basis for my comment.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused than when I started. I created this cfiddle by directly copying from the source file and commenting out Die/adding main: http://cfiddle.net/LwucyB As you can see it compiles fine... No idea what's going on now.

Comment: @user1509246.. well .. it may be a case where you may not have saved the file and tried to compile or something similar.

Comment: Ah.. Ok turns out that I am a shit-brained moron who shouldn't be allowed to use a computer. When i made the original post i changed the function slightly to stop it from being so messy. In the original definition one of the arguments is named "History". Yup, i'm that dumb. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.



  EDIT: As a side note, it would be real nice if GCC told you about defining local variables with the same name as global ones, oh well.

Comment: @user1509246.. Nope it happens to everyone. I have updated my answer including a note on the allocation of `NewNode`. Please accept if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to malloc sizeof(HistoryNode), not NewNode (which is a pointer to a HistoryNode).

Comment: Hmm, when I add this I get this error:
Scribe.c:504:29: error: 'HistoryNode' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: In the question, we can observe that `HistoryNode` is not a `typedef`. Hence, when we need to allocate we need to specify `malloc(sizeof(struct HistoryNode));`. However, allocating a pointer is syntactically fine even though it is incorrect from a logical perspective.